# "Computed property names" for getters and setters in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Javascript has the syntax

```
class C {
   get [prop]() { ... }
   set [prop](v) { ... }
}
```

for getting or setting arbitrary properties.

is there any way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: JavaScript is TypeScript. Your code works as is.

Comment: [This is the documentation for getter/setter](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/).

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ymp7zN) meet your needs?  How "arbitrary" are these properties?  Could you make a [mcve] suitable for dropping into an IDE that othere can use to demonstrate the issue for themselves?

Comment: @jcalz I meant that I want to use the variable `prop` inside the getter or setter.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ymp7zN) or not?  If it is not, then please elaborate in your question with a [mcve] someone can look at in their IDE.  Right now I have to guess how you are defining `prop` and how you are using it.

Comment: @jcalz here is a minimal reproducible example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XQOYFMAu0DaADgE4D2BAugBQCUi0wJAdhCSJgHQgnqUAGW2bAEtG6aABIExMgF9e1ANzQZKNBBz5pFSgDdaCekxZtO3PusEixkrTOjYSEhDrmLlSFUgbNcwaAF5oRkwAdzgaBS92ADMSR0CAIgAjMCIEyKQAekzoCAALEgBXEAATaGIRXASLYVFoWMcHaBS0oA

Comment: @Adrian this should look like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XQOYFMAu0BmA9gQBQCUi0wBAdhASJgHQgHrEAGW22AlteviLtSAbmgAnHAFdx1aAHIwS+WIC+KNBByCSAN3IJKNOg2asOW7nwGEC0bHYAkCXauFqk6pFVq5g0AF5oakwAdzgyEW9GW0DoACIAIzBxeKikAHoM6AgACwIpEAATaAAHcT5ceMtefh17O2TUoA You need to replace `[prop]` with a real prop name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code doesn't actually do what you're trying to do, even in JavaScript.  [*Computed property names*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) work by evaluating an expression to come up with the property name.  For example:

```
const computed = {
    ["foo".toUpperCase()]: "bar"
}
console.log(computed.FOO) // bar
```

Unless `prop` is already an existing variable, using `prop` as a computed property will just fail.  Each computed property will only be used as a single property, and not all possible properties.

---

I think the only way to intercept *all* property gets and sets in JavaScript (and therefore in TypeScript) is to use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  Here's one possible implementation:

```
class C {
    [k: string]: any;
    constructor() {
        return new Proxy<C>(this, {
            get(thiz, prop) {
                console.log(`getting ${String(prop)}`);
            },
            set(thiz, prop, v) {
                console.log(`setting ${String(prop)} to ${v}`);
                return true;             }
        });
    }
}
```

We're telling TypeScript that an instance of class `C` has a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) so that it will accept any property key (and `any` property value).  Then, the `constructor()` method explicitly returns a `Proxy` so that when you [call the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on it you will get the proxy instead of the default `this`.

Anyway the proxy implements a [`get` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) and a [`set` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) and so it intercepts all gets and sets for all properties.  The property key name is passed into the handler methods, and so you can actually get the behavior you're looking for:

```
const c = new C();
c.foo; // getting foo
c.foo = "bar"; // setting foo to bar
```

Note: I recommend that you use great care and test any code like the above before using it in a production environment; there may well be edge cases involved with returning custom objects in a class constructor, or with the particular `Proxy` handlers shown.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC2AHArlApgExgXhgbwCgZiYBtAIgDMQRyA6KEAVUUTQCcBhAQwjQAoAlAF0AXDHIAjbu3IEAvgVCQQAGzR1VIAOb8EKdBjoAxAPKnBMAPRWY09gUfBVvCDE74iJUgGtx0dgBLMG0xGG4wAE8Abi9iZQDkYEZ2IU8SDJh2NChkdjAYMDQAdxgABXYQAA9IgB5OAD5+KAALQIgAGnTMnu0c5raALy7ESsRLQh6pkgS1DS1dAAM+qChg7RgAEjwAZSggkP5RkHH5RcFY6Yz5DrirvigBwOGYY8QugDcJu6uZ8Ag5podPxFg81iEtrt9usjmNBPIYIxIR8zhcfr8sjk8gV9sg0JcMYppvI0dcFI4lP9YMAcIUSu4hLFgHRqCBotZbCtwRtWUoWTRaVIZOR2TYYGD1jBWYiQHYZBSgA)